# How to improve the perfomance of SVM?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

Im using LIBSVM and MatLab to classify 34x5 data in 3 classes. I applied 10 fold Kfold cross validation method and RBF kernel. The output is this confusion matrix with 0.88 Correct rate (88 % accuracy). This is my confusion matrix

```
9   0   0
0   3   0
0   4   18
```

I would like to know what methods inside SVM to consider to improve the accuracy or other classifications method in Machine learning techniques. Any help?

Here is my SVM classification code

```
load Turn180SVM1; //load data file
libsvm_options = '-s 1 -t 2 -d 3 -r 0 -c 1 -n 0.1 -p 0.1 -m 100 -e 0.000001 -h 1 -b 0 -wi 1 -q';//svm options

C=size(Turn180SVM1,2);

% cross validation
for i = 1:10
    indices = crossvalind('Kfold',Turn180SVM1(:,C),10);
    cp = classperf(Turn180SVM1(:,C)); 
    for j = 1:10
        [X, Z] = find(indices(:,end)==j);%testing
        [Y, Z] = find(indices(:,end)~=j);%training


feature_training = Turn180SVM1([Y'],[1:C-1]); feature_testing = Turn180SVM1([X'],[1:C-1]);
class_training = Turn180SVM1([Y'],end); class_testing = Turn180SVM1([X'], end);
% SVM Training
       disp('training');
       [feature_training,ps] = mapminmax(feature_training',0,1);
       feature_training = feature_training';
       feature_testing = mapminmax('apply',feature_testing',ps)';
       model = svmtrain(class_training,feature_training,libsvm_options);  
% 

% SVM Prediction       
        disp('testing');
        TestPredict = svmpredict(class_testing,sparse(feature_testing),model);
       TestErrap = sum(TestPredict~=class_testing)./length(class_testing)*100;
         cp = classperf(cp, TestPredict, X);
        disp(((i-1)*10 )+j);
end;
end;
[ConMat,order] = confusionmat(TestPredict,class_testing);
cp.CorrectRate;
cp.CountingMatrix;
```

Comment: from the above confusion matrix, it seems that you dont have a lot of instances. If you can, try to get more data which might help (as long you understand the [bias-variance](http://followthedata.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/practical-advice-for-machine-learning-bias-variance/) [tradeoff](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html) by plotting learning curves)

Comment: Yes, true. Have 34 instances. How to plot the learning curve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4617365/97160

Comment: But whats the command to plot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many methods exist. If your tuning procedure is optimal (e.g. well executed cross-validation) your choices include:

1. Improve preprocessing, perhaps tailor new aggregated features based on domain knowledge. Most importantly (and most effectively): make sure your inputs are standardized properly, for example by scaling every dimension onto [-1,1].
2. Use another kernel: RBF kernels are known to perform very well in a wide variety of settings, but specialised kernels exist for many tasks. Don't consider this unless you know what you are doing. Since you are dealing with a low-dimensional problem, RBF is probably a good choice if your data is not structured.
3. Reweigh training instances: particularly important when your data set is unbalanced (e.g. some classes have a lot less instances than others). You can do this with the `-wX` options in libsvm. All sorts of reweighting schemes exist, including variants of boosting. I'm not a major fan of this, since such approaches are prone to overfitting.
4. Change the cross-validation cost function to suit your exact needs. Is accuracy really what you are looking for or do you want, say, high [F1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) or high [ROC-AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)? It is surprising how many people optimize a performance measure they are not *really* interested in.

Comment: How to check if my tuning procedure is optimal?What do you mean in 4 by high F1? And any tips for using other methods but not SVM?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have higher accuracy. So to speak to speak to have a diagonal confusion matrix. So I would like to get rid of the 4 in the non diagonal in confusion matrix.

Comment: You can try to assign higher weights to instances of class 3 (in row 3) in the 3-vs-rest classifier, or lower weights to class 2 in 3-vs-rest. Note that such fiddling is not considered good practice, since it appears you are attempting to optimize test set performance by changing your training parameters. This will induce overfitting.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have higher accuracy. So to speak, my ultimate goal is to have a pure diagonal confusion matrix. So I would like to get rid of the 4 in the non diagonal in confusion matrix

Comment: Ok. I will try that. And how about some other classification Machine Learning methods? Like, DBN, or feature management or Markov decision process?

Comment: How to change the cross-validation function ? You mean to use HoldOut or other Method?