# Testing the maximum theoretical accuracy for a data set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, prediction

I am applying several machine learning methods to a real-world medical data set but I can't achieve high accuracy (its around 80% now) for the test data set. The problem is to predict if the disease is present or not.

Is there any way to prove how much maximum accuracy can be achieved? Or something similar that can tell the expected accuracy of a particular machine learning model for the data set?

If not, how can I prove the accuracy I am getting is the best (or near best) accuracy possible from the data set?

Comment: I don't think anything like this exists. Do you have any benchmark for this problem?

Comment: No benchmark is available. I just need to theoretically prove the accuracy I am getting is the best (close to best) accuracy possible from the data set. @FilipeLauar

Comment: It's not an answer to the actual question, but to get some insights, it could be interesting to create some learning curves: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617365/what-is-a-learning-curve-in-machine-learning

Comment: So I don't think it's possible. The best result is always an accuracy of 100%. The best accuracy for your problem depends on your data and the model you are using. If 80% isn't good enough for your aplication, you should consider do feature engineering and test other models and algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how deterministic your data is. I will illustrate with two variables, y as a function of x.

If y = x, then the theoretical best accuracy is 100%. It should be possible to get a perfect result.

Now suppose that y = x + rnorm(n, 0, sigma) where n is the number of points and you get to choose sigma. You can predict x, but you cannot predict the random part. The bigger sigma is, the worse your predictions. You can make the best possible accuracy arbitrarily low by choosing a large enough sigma.

With real data, you don't usually know how well your input variables determine the output, so you cannot state a meaningful theoretical limit just accuracy is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

What is the accuracy rate for the detections done by humans?

If it is almost the accuracy you get via the machine, you are doing great! Even if the machine is doing a bit worse, it can even be considered good.

In the industry, such a question is mostly Product management questions rather than a scientific one.

Comment: Do you mean calculating the prior probability? The percentage that were identified by the hospital/doctors?

Comment: Right. That normally gives you a rule of thumb. if you get much better than doctors, so maybe you do not care too much for further accuracy improvement. If you get less, it might still be acceptable depending on the product, or you might have rooms for the improvment.